# Windows using Bootcamp won't read any USB memory sticks

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, external-disk

I just installed Windows 10 on my MacBook (Early 2015, OSX El Capitan 10.11.2), and after everything set up I tried to plug in my External Hard Drive.  I made sure this HD would and does work in Windows 10 by plugging it into another laptop I have running only Windows 10, and it worked fine there.

When I plug it into my MacBook with Windows 10 running, it:

- Shows the notification asking what I want to do with the HD, I close it.
- Doesn't show a Windows Explorer popup appears with the contents of the HD.

After this I go to Windows Explorer manually and try to open it.  2 things happen with this.

1. I notice the drive is called "Local Drive" instead of its actual name, "My Passport" (named that because the drive is WD My Passport).
2. When I go to open the HD, it gives me an error I have never seen before, `Invalid Parameters`.

When I first saw this I safely ejected the HD, and I got the BSOD with an error of `KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE`.  I guessed it was a problem with the safe eject feature, so I rebooted and ejected it without the safe eject function, and it gave me the same BSOD error.

Before anyone marks this as "off-topic", this is about Apple's drivers in Windows, not Windows itself, as the [causes of the BSOD error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj569891(v=vs.85).aspx) suggest.  None of the Windows updates seem to fix it, and I seem to be unable to find any driver fixes from apple.

**Update**: I can no longer even plug the HD into the computer, because when I plug it in it plays the little "Device Connected" chime, then the computer gives me the BSOD withe the same error.

Comment: Which Macbook & OS?

Comment: MacBook (early 2015), OSX El Capitan (10.11.2), Windows 10

Comment: Make sure to have your USB formatted as FAT, and also, I have had issues with some hidden files generated by OS X like .fsevented. You can remove these by `rm -rf /Volumes/VolName/.fsevented`. Also delete Spotlight_V100. You can prevent its creation with `touch /Volumes/VolName/.metadata_never_index`. Make sure to replace VolName with the name of your mounted volume

Comment: @TheBro21 as I mentioned above, this HD works on another laptop running Windows 10.  I have it formatted as exFAT, and sadly deleting those folders did nothing.

Comment: Does it work in the Mac install?

Comment: @FlareCat it does.

Comment: @Jaketr00 So then it is not hardware related. Try reinstalling Apple's Bootcamp drivers (make sure you go into the bootcamp app on mac, and download the newest drivers). If that doesn't work, then I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @FlareCat I just finished downloading and installing the drivers again, and it is still doing the same thing

Comment: @Jaketr00 well, I don't know what to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to finally fix this.  All I did was reformat the External HD as the "MS-DOS(FAT)" filesystem through Disk Utility.

I'm assuming it was an issue with the "ExFAT" filesystem, although I could plug it into 2 other Windows laptops in my house with ExFAT.